# Omit typescript compiling when doing ng build?

Tags: angular-cli

```
        "build": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
            "options": {
                "outputPath": "build/client-dist",
                "index": "client/index.html",
                "main": "client/main.ts",
                "polyfills": "client/polyfills.ts",
                "tsConfig": "tsconfig.client.json", // <----- remove this?
                "assets": ["client/favicon.ico", "client/assets"],
                "styles": ["client/styles.scss"],
                "scripts": [],
                "es5BrowserSupport": true
```

Is there a way to stop `ng build` from using webpacks `ts-loader` to compile typescript to javascript. I do this in a separate step outside of angular/webpack.

Comment: Did you have some error when you remove it ?

Comment: @R3tep "Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should have required property 'tsConfig'."

Comment: Sounds like you need to eject your project or create your own builder. Maybe you can get somewhere if you change the `main` to the compiled `main.js`. I just feel like you will be missing a lot of optimizations

Comment: @PierreDuc Yea I tried to use the ""builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser"," however now I need a webpack.config.js which will work. I have no idea how to get a hold of this. ng eject won't work: "The 'eject' command has been disabled and will be removed completely in 8.0.
The new configuration format provides increased flexibility to modify the
configuration of your workspace without ejecting."

Comment: @KarlMorrison alright, i did remember reading something about eject being deprecated. I have no experience with creating a custom builder, but you could check this link https://blog.angular.io/introducing-cli-builders-d012d4489f1b